# My links become "un-clickable" when I use position absolute... How do I fix?

Tags: html, css, positioning, hyperlink

```
<div id="cart-login" style="position:absolute;right:50px;top:30px;">
    <a href="login.php">LOGIN</a> or <a href="sign-in.php">SIGN UP</a> <a href="cart.php" class="no-underline">CART</a>
</div>
```

I've done this many, many times, yet for some reason the links become unclickable this time. I have tried `float:right; margin-right:50px;` and `position:absolute; right:50px;`. Both render the links and text non-selectable and non-clickable. I've even tried `z-index` in case there is an invisible layer somewhere. Why would all the links on the page work but these links not work? The links are fine until I apply `position:absolute; right:50px;` then they are disabled but visible on the page. Any solutions?

Comment: The problem isn't with the code you've posted: http://jsfiddle.net/X49hs/

Comment: We cannot judge from this code alone. We need more from the surrounding code.

Comment: Try do reenact your code step by step in a jsfiddle and you perhaps will get the solution yourself. If not, give the link to the fiddle here.

Answer (score 1):

`div` elements are by default set to occupy 100% width. Once set to `position:absolute` their width and height are determined by their content. Try giving `#cart-login` explicit height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give an higher `z-index`, maybe something is over the element.

Comment: The question specifies that this was already tried, and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using a fixed ul with li menu links, increasing the z-index exposed the links again.